# Laravel Eloquent join three table-has many through

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

Hi I have three tables

**organisation**

```
 id | name
 1  | org1
 2  | org2
```

**site**

```
id | name  | organisation_id
1  | site1 | 1
2  | site2 | 1
3  | site3 | 2
```

**service**

```
id | name     | site_id
1  | service1 | 1
2  | service2 | 1
3  | service2 | 2
```

Here I want to get all the services of organisation (let say 1).
I can get all the sites of organisation like this but how do I get services:

```php
$sites = Site::whereHas('organisation', function ($query) {
    $query->where('id', 1);
})->get();
```

**Model**

**organisationModel**

```php
public function sites() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Site');
}
```

**siteModel**

```php
public function organisation(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Organisation');
}

public function services() {
     return $this->hasMany('App\Service');
}
```

**serviceModel**

```php
public function site(){
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Site');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get like relationship with ['has many through'](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through):

**Model organisation**:

```php
public function services()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Service::class, Site::class, 'organisation_id', 'site_id', 'id');
}
```

**To get**:

```
$services = Organisation::find(1)->services;
```

Or you can get all services with [nested](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) **whereHas**:

```php
$services = Service::whereHas('site.organisation', function ($query) {
    $query->where('organisation.id', 1);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get in this way :

```
Site::with('organisation')
          ->select('id', 'name')
          ->with(['services' => function ($q) {
                   return $q->select('id', 'name');
            }])
           ->where('organisation_id', 1)
           ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be acheived without whereHas with [nested eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loads)

```
$organization=Organization::with('sites','sites.services')->where(['id'=>1])->first();
foreach($organization->sites as $site)
{
    foreach($site->services as $service)
    {
        print_r($service->name);
    }
}
```